# Multiply Cell range by textbox value input

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to multiply a range of cells by the value of a textbox that the user inputs. My code keeps giving me a `Type Mismatch` error. How should I change my code?

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("F2:F25")
        cell.Formula = TextBox2.Value * Range("E2:E25").Value
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `cell.Value = TextBox2.Value * cell.Offset(,-1).Value`

Answer (score 1):

`Range("E2:E25").Value` is a 2D array.

If you want to successively multiply `F2`, `F3`, `F4` by `E2`, `E3`, `E4`, then use `Offset` as you loop:

```
cell.Value = TextBox2.Value * cell.Offset(,-1).Value
```

Comment: nicely done,... :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, thank you. It is good to see you in these parts!